# Where to store realm connection in react-native?

Tags: react-native, realm

I want to build an app and I don't know where I should store realm connection and credentials for it.

I found that there is `AsyncStorage` and it can be used for storing credentials. But how should I deal with realm? Should I create singleton and store connection in it or are there better solutions?

Now I have such file but I'm not sure that it's good solution:

```
export default Realm.Sync.User.login(REALM_SERVER_URL, 'username', 'password').then(user => {
  return Realm.open({
    sync: {
      user: user,
      url: `realm://${REALM_HOST}/~/ownLists`,
    },
    schema: [List, ListItem]
  })
})
```

Comment: Is http://randycoulman.com/blog/2017/07/25/secure-storage-in-react-native/ useful?

Comment: This looks good for storing credentials. But what about storing a connection at runtime?

Comment: You can get it with https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/api/Realm.html#syncSession. But the session is maintained by the sync client, and you will not likely need to access it directly.

Comment: Somewhere I build `realm = Realm.open(...)`. Where should I store it not to have any performance problems and make it accessible in a whole app?

Comment: Since Realm instances are cached, `Realm.open()` is actually a cheap operation. So it might be easier open when needed.

Comment: This sounds good, I'll try it.